# What to do with this simple question?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46171/3804) question seems very simple and easy to answer. In fact it tempts users to post link only answers.

Its not a true list question in my mind but it still doesn't sit right with me. I want to close, and I don't.

Does the community have any thoughtsthou on this?

Comment: When I can, I try to point them someplace that already does this, and summarize it in the answer.  For example, [this question about Stargate "arc" episodes](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20204/is-there-a-list-of-stargate-arc-episodes-anywhere)

Comment: Frankly, I'm strongly suspicious of any claim of "this is trivially answerable" not backed up by... well, a trivially obtained **answer** ... \*hint\* \*hint\*

Answer (score 5):

I think the question shows little to no research effort, but it's essentially a [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question, where the 'story' is a story arc.  I'm fine with leaving it, but I'm downvoting the answers that are just links.

I'm also downvoting because neither of those answers actually answer the question.  If I ask you which episodes of a show contain an element, and you just link me to a list of every episode, you're not answering my question.  That's essentially what these answers are doing, in addition to just being links.

Comment: Well, it finally got an actual answer to the question.  I'm giving them a cookie as thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I share Keen's opinion of the current answers, however, in concept **it's a perfectly valid question** ("which of the episodes of a show constitute a specific story arc") not nearly worthy of VTCing and perfectly on-topic and in-scope.

If you feel that the answer is trivial to obtain (not being an SME, I don't see how it would be), you can and should:

(1) Post the correct answer - as Izkata stated, a link to existing resource would be a good format<sup>[1]</sup>.

(2) Down-vote the question for not doing obvious research, ...

(2b) ... ideally with a comment explaining to noobs like me JUST what you did to research it as learning aid.

---

<sub>[1] - IMHO, we have enough rep whores on SFF.SE that if it was, indeed, trivially answerable, we would more likely than not have already seen a good correct answer. The fact that one is missing leads me to be slightly skeptical of your assessment concerning the simplicity of answering it</sub>